# Import Historical Records from Excel to Custom App

Tags: excel, import, legacy

I need a bit of help. My company has data in multiple excel sheets. Some sheets are straight forward (in that they easily map data types). But most of them are merged rows and cells etc within one header. I am developing an application in c# for maintaining a massive database with proper user and role management and multiple departments as stake holders.

I have identified the relations from within the excel sheets and all is well. What I cannot understand is how to import that historical data to map to the data tables? Basically, when a new custom system is designed, how would you import senseless data within it?

The only thing I could think of was writing a utility program that reads every row and every cell of the excel sheets and then extract the required values to insert to the proper database table. But this would take ages due to the numerous number of excel sheets.

Wondering anyone of you went through the same thing as I have?How did or would you handle this?

Many thanks guys :)

Comment: When you say *this would take ages*, do you mean that it would take ages for the import utility program to run and complete? Are you sure about that? Can you support that statement with measurements? Or do you mean it would take ages to write such a utility due to the different kinds of sheets?

Comment: Apologies for that: by ages I meant writing such a program. (Well actually not ages, but lets just say for something that would take a few weeks to write, management would like in a day or two. How would I go about that?

Answer (score 0):

If the data is not regular, you've got a world of pain ahead of you. The object model in Excel can be driven by any of the Windows Scripting Host languages, like VBScript and JScript. In fact, most scripting languages have some support for Excel traversal.

However, as you've already noted, the data layout isn't the same across all spreadsheets. I had a similar problem years ago traversing SCADA data from power stations: each station did it slightly differently and changed their format from time to time.